# Why isn't this PHP function call working

Tags: php, function, parameters, return-value

I've spent a great deal of time debugging this code, and I can't figure out why this function call fails. If I remove the function call and put the function's code directly in-line, it works fine, but as soon as I break it out into a function, it fails.

I've placed the function in the code before it is being called, I even tried placing it in the function that calls it, but it doesn't work.

The function:

```
function parsetime($datestring) {
    $dateelements = explode("T", $datestring);
    $time = substr($dateelements[1], 0, strlen($dateelements[1]) - 3);
    return $time;
}
```

I'm calling the function with the code below:

```
foreach ($xml->Schedule->children() as $ScheduledMatch) {

    // Collect the data for the table
    $match = str_replace('Qualification ', '', $ScheduledMatch->description);
    $dateelements = explode("T", $ScheduledMatch->startTime);

    $time = parsetime($ScheduledMatch->startTime);

    foreach ($ScheduledMatch->Teams->children() as $Team) {
        if ($Team->teamNumber == $team) {
            $alliance = substr($Team->station, 0, strlen($Team->station) - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm relatively new to PHP, but according to the PHP docs and some examples I've seen on the web, there's nothing special about defining a function or returning a value. Am I missing something simple?

Comment: Is it giving any error ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but you might need to break `parsetime($ScheduledMatch->startTime)` up and assign `$ScheduledMatch->startTime` to an independent variable, and then pass that as the function parameter.

Comment: whats the vale of `$ScheduledMatch->startTime` ?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay I'm not getting an error that I can see. A sample of the content of $ScheduledMatch->startTime would be: 2018-03-29T10:22:00

Comment: is this function is in the class?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay It is in the class.

Comment: Try to call the function like this: `$time = $this->parsetime($ScheduledMatch->startTime);`

Comment: @Prdufresne, it worked?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay I stepped away, but I just tried your suggestion, and it worked. Please post your solution as an answer, and I will select it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's beyond the scope of your question, but what is the date string before start hacking away at it?  Surely there is a cleaner way.  You probably don't need to make a function call at all.

Comment: @mickmackusa In this particular example, since I'm also using the date, you are correct, a single line of code could replace the function, but I need to parse out the time at several points in the code, so creating a function makes sense.

Comment: Okay, then your function needs to be cleaned up.  What is the input value and expected return?

Comment: A sample of the content of $ScheduledMatch->startTime would be: 2018-03-29T10:22:00 and I just want the hours and minutes of the time, so 10:22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call the function like this:

```
$time = $this->parsetime($ScheduledMatch->startTime);
```